# How to push multiple data in same object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I need to push id from firebase in same object. Problem is that i need to save in same object and not in the new one.

```
db.collection("form").where("posted_at", ">=", 1)
.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
querySnapshot.forEach(doc=> {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    this.array.push(doc.data()); //if i do something like this: this.array.push(doc.data(),{id:doc.id}); it saves but in new object
});
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
db.collection("form").where("posted_at", ">=", 1)
.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc=> {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    this.array.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
  });
})
```

Alternatively, if the [spread syntax](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_spread_spread_in_object_literals) isn't supported by your platform, you can use `Object.assign()` like so:

```js
db.collection("form").where("posted_at", ">=", 1)
.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc=> {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    this.array.push(Object.assign({}, doc.data(), {id: doc.id}));
  });
})
```